# JetBrains Rider - "Search Everywhere" command different to one triggered by Shift+Shift

Tags: jetbrains-ide

Seen in both Rider and IntelliJ:

I want to rebind the command triggered by a double tap of <kbd>Shift</kbd>, which by default brings up this dialog:
[image: dialog from "shift+shift"]

My understanding was this was the "Search Everywhere" command, but if I run that command I get the following:
[image: dialog from "Search Everywhere" command]

What is the command run by a double tap of shift called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have assigned that shortcut to the wrong action.

I'm not using Rider... but in PhpStorm (another IDE built on IDEA platform) it will locate 2 matches (as seen on screenshot below) when you search for `everywhere` on the "Keymap" screen.

The correct action is `Main menu | Navigate | Search Everywhere`. For me it bring the same popup as double <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

[image]

**P.S.** Once again: the screenshot is from PhpStorm 2020.2.1. It may look different in Rider (but similar in IntelliJ).

Comment: Easy as that! Interestingly, I had discounted that previously due to the fact that selecting that other command from the Find Actions thing didn't actually work, but assigning a shortcut and then using that shortcut did work